# Significance of "Fm"

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run this query

```
 SELECT TO_CHAR(0, 'Fm99.99')    FROM DUAL;
```

I got `0.` as output in oracle 10g.

But when I run

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0, '99.99')    FROM DUAL;
```

this gives  `.00` as output.

Please explain what is the significance of `FM` and how these two query behave differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fm signifies that you dont want the leading characters.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref451):

> Fill mode. Oracle uses trailing blank characters and leading zeroes to
>   fill format elements to a constant width. The width is equal to the
>   display width of the largest element for the relevant format model
>
> **The FM modifier suppresses the above padding in the return value of
>   the TO_CHAR function.**

Answer (score 0):

The fm (fill mode) operator removes extra spaces in months, days in the TO_CHAR function for the date.